# Docker fedora hbase JAVA_HOME issue

Tags: docker, hbase, fedora

My dockerfile on fedora 22

```
FROM java:latest

ENV HBASE_VERSION=1.1.0.1

RUN groupadd -r hbase && useradd -m -r -g hbase hbase

USER hbase
ENV HOME=/home/hbase
# Download'n extract hbase
RUN cd /home/hbase && \
    wget -O - -q \
    http://apache.mesi.com.ar/hbase/${HBASE_VERSION}/hbase-${HBASE_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
    | tar --strip-components=1 -zxf -

# Upload local configuration
ADD ./conf/ /home/hbase/conf/
USER root
RUN chown -R hbase:hbase /home/hbase/conf
USER hbase

# Prepare data volumes
RUN mkdir /home/hbase/data
RUN mkdir /home/hbase/logs

VOLUME /home/hbase/data
VOLUME /home/hbase/logs

# zookeeper
EXPOSE 2181
# HBase Master API port
EXPOSE 60000
# HBase Master Web UI
EXPOSE 60010
# Regionserver API port
EXPOSE 60020
# HBase Regionserver web UI
EXPOSE 60030

WORKDIR /home/hbase
CMD /home/hbase/bin/hbase master start
```

As I understand when I set "FROM java:latest" my current dockerfile overlays on that one, so JAVA_HOME must be setted as it is in java:latest? Am I right? This Dockerfile is builded, but when I "docker run" image, It shows "JAVA_HOME not found" error. How can I properly set it up?

Comment: use the ENV directive, something like `ENV JAVA_HOME /abc/def`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the ENV directive, something like `ENV JAVA_HOME /abc/def` the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env

Answer (score 0):

add to `~./bashrc` (or for global `/etc/bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```